# Read-only cronjobs for users

Tags: permissions, cron

Here's a weird issue. I want to make crontab for a user that is read-only for that particular user and can only be managed via root. Sounds easy? Here's the catch:

```
$ ls -alh /var/spool/cron/my_user
-r-------- 1 root root 386 May  8 15:13 /var/spool/cron/my_user
```

So, the file is owned/grouped for root and only has read privileges (0400) for root.

The catch:

```
$ su - my_user
my_user~$ crontab -e
(write something to the crontab)
crontab: installing new crontab
$ ls -alh /var/spool/cron/my_user
-rw------- 1 my_user my_user 386 May  8 15:13 /var/spool/cron/my_user
```

So a file owned by root, with read-only privileges by root, could be read by a non-privileged user and was then modified to a 0600 (rw) and owned for that user?

What obvious catch am I missing?

Comment: You can add the jobs to the root user crontab using `sudo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

crontab is setuid.  So users can update their crontab.

What version of cron are you running.  If you are running a version that supports putting fragements in `/etc/cron.d` then you should do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use the system /etc/crontab file instead of a user contab.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `/var/spool/cron/my_user` immutable after you install the modifications you desire to prevent changes.

`sudo chattr +i /var/spool/cron/my_user`

Comment: `sudo chattr +i /var/spool/cron/crontabs/my_user` for ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can add the user to `/etc/cron.deny`. This will deny the user access to the command `crontab` and she cannot edit her crontab anymore.

AFAICT an entry in `/etc/cron.deny` does *not* disable the defined cronjobs.